# push_back in the vector class in C++

Tags: c++

This is a snapshot of my code:

```
int m = 3;
int l = 4;
int k - 6;
std::vector<int> perceptrons;
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    Perceptron Ki = Perceptron(m, l);
    perceptrons.push_back(Ki);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Main.cpp:102:33: error: no matching function for call to       ‘std::vector<int>::push_back(Perceptron&)’
     perceptrons.push_back(Ki);
```

I have a class Perceptron that are objects with the parameters m and l also obviously, basically I'm just trying to create a Vector of perceptrons.

Can anybody see why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Obviously it's because you have a `vector` of `int`s and you're trying to add a `Perceptron` to it. The only way this will work is if the `Perceptron` class has an implicit type conversion operator to `int` defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're trying to put a `Perceptron` into a vector of `ints`.

Change your code to:

```
int m = 3;
int l = 4;
int k - 6;
std::vector<Perceptron> perceptrons; // This is the line that needs changing
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    Perceptron Ki = Perceptron(m, l);
    perceptrons.push_back(Ki);
}
```

Comment: How would I then reference the specific integers within the Perceptron, notably 'l'? Thanks.

Comment: `perceptrons[0].l` perhaps? `perceptrons[x]` evaluates as `Perceptron &` so you can use it like you would any other `Perceptron` object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a different kind of vector:

```
std::vector<Perceptron> perceptrons;
```

Hopefully those are cheap to copy.